# Как узнать message_id, отправленного самим ботом?

Tags: python, telebot

Представим, что бот отправил сообщение

```
   bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "123")
```

```
   BOT: 123
```

Как узнать message_id этого сообщения?

Comment: Заключить строку отправки сообщения в `print()`?

Comment: @Violet Если сделать так, то выведется объект сообщения. С таким методом надо написать отправку и добавить .message_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bot.send_message возвращает сообщение которое было отправлено. Если дописать после метода as msg и после чего прописать print(msg.message_id), то бот выведет id отправленного сообщения.